# OpenLayers zoom on a collection of points

Tags: openlayers, point, zoom

I'm new to OpenLayers, but I have a working map with 5 points based on GPS coords working.  however, it's not zooming to the extents of the points.  Wondering what I've done wrong (could very well be a typo, JavaScript is not my forte...).  the "adjust_map_zoom" function is where my problem lies, i believe.

The map is generated, the points are all there and the map is initially set to the mapDefaultZoom setting.  If I change that initialize setting, the zoom changes.  however, as the points spread apart and then come back together, the zoom doesn't change to fit their new boundaries.

```
var map;
var mapLat = <?php echo $xcenter; ?>;
var mapLng = <?php echo $ycenter; ?>;
var mapDefaultZoom = 12;

function initialize_map() {
  map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            target: "tile",
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                  url: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([mapLng, mapLat]),
        zoom: mapDefaultZoom
    })
  });
}

function add_map_point(lat, lng) {
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    target: "points",
    source:new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        })]
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "fraction",
        src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/RedDot.svg"
      })
    })
  });

  map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
}


function adjust_map_zoom(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  map.getView().fit(ol.proj.transformExtent([ x1, y1, x2, y2 ], 'EPSG:COORDS', 'EPSG:MAP'), {size:map.getSize(), maxZoom:18});
}
```

if i change the adjust_map_zoom code to

```
map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), {size:map.getSize(), maxZoom:16});
```

or even

```
map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

the zoom does not change at all.

Could someone point out my mistake please?  the bulk of the code was copied from online examples.

Comment: Where and how  is `source` defined?

Comment: `source: new ol.source.OSM({`  i thought it was defined under the first block in the initialize function.  I wondered if this was a problem, but i tried giving it a title and referencing the title, and it still didn't work.  Again, not my forte :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reference some variable, it has to be defined in the scope you are referencing it. Solution here would be to define `vectorLayer` as a global variable so that you can later reference it anywhere.

Also you have to define/create vector layer only once, and then add features to this layer, otherwise each point will have it's own layer.

So code could then look something like this:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  target: "points",
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: "fraction",
      anchorYUnits: "fraction",
      src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/RedDot.svg"
    })
  })
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

function add_map_point(lat, lng) {
  var source = vectorLayer.getSource();
  var pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  });
  source.addFeature(pointFeature);
}
```

You can then zoom to the layer extent with:

```
map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), {
  size: map.getSize(),
  maxZoom: 16
});
```

Comment: Woo Hoo!  Genius!  It's changing zoom dynamically!  however, it's only zooming on 1 point, and it's not centering between the 5 points any longer, so I'm thinking it's only zooming on the last point added, not all the points.  I'll go back to sending in the bounds coords and see if that works.  Is there a way to get the extents for all the points/layers in the map dynamically?  thanks :)

Comment: another thought - it would appear each point is going on a new layer (if I'm reading the code correctly).  would it be better or is there a way to get all the points on one layer?

Comment: You are right, I was not attentive enough to the possible logic of the app. See modified answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help - learned something new, and got a simple working page as well.  Much appreciated :)

Comment: for anyone interested, if you want to know what the zoom setting is after it's done it's thing, modify the adjust_map_zoom function as follows:

`function adjust_map_zoom() {
map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), {size:map.getSize(), maxZoom:16});
var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
alert(zoom);
}`